# preg_replace to capture inside Image tags

Tags: regex, html-parsing, preg-replace

Hi There I am hoping that someone can help me with this `preg_replace` problem that I have

I have the following `preg_replace("/(\/[^\/]*.jpg)/", ".jpg", $input_lines);`

the idea is to replace images in my wordpress site to their original name... The file already exists in the non cache folder so I do not need to worry about that part...

```
<img src="http://url.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2014/02/flag/278439615.jpg">
```

I have a replace that takes care of the `cache` in the url so I am left with the URL like this:

```
<img src="http://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/flag/278439615.jpg">
```

Now the next step would be to strip the `number.jpg` from the URL the number can be alphabetical or numbers.

The constant in all URL's is the last occurance of the `/` and the `.jpg` which the `preg_replace("/(\/[^\/]*.jpg)/", ".jpg", $input_lines);` takes care of

The problem however is that the preg_replace needs to look for the tags in the image tag and not replace any code that is not in the image tag...

**How would I add to the regex (preg_replace) to look only inside the image tags for the replacement?**

The ideal end result would be a URL that looks like this:

```
<img src="http://url.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/flag.jpg">
```

The regex (preg_replace) also need to replace all occurances of the match (There might be more than one image on the page).

Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this replacement:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~
<img \s
(?> [^>s]++ | \Bs | s(?!rc\s*=) )* # possible content before the src attribute 
src \s* = \s* ["']? [^"\'\s>]+?    # start of the src attribute (until /cache/)
\K                                 # reset all from match result
/cache(?=/)
([^\s"'>]*?)                       # capture the path before the filename
/[^\s/]+ (?=\.jpg [>"'\s])         # the filename followed by the .jpg extension
~ix
EOD;
$result = preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $input_lines);
```